# Flask Restplus disable API Endpoint when condition does not meet

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask-restful, flask-restplus

Can I know how to disable flask restplus endpoint?

I am trying to do something like when a condition does not meet, the endpoint is disabled and cannot be accessed.

Is there a way we can do this in flask restplus or custom code is required?

I know that we can disable the endpoint in swagger documentation. However, that doesn't disable the endpoint as it stills can be accessed via curl. http://localhost:8080/api_endpoint/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `add_url_rule` in the Flask docs:

From the Flask docs, http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/

```
Internally route() invokes add_url_rule() so if you want to customize the behavior via subclassing you only need to change this method.

For more information refer to URL Route Registrations.
```